# Enforcing the verify-full option when connecting to AWS RDS using node

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have the following `node` script

```js
const { Pool } = require('pg');
const { parse } = require('pg-connection-string');

const config = parse(process.env.DATABASE_URL);
config.ssl = { rejectUnauthorized: true };

const pool = new Pool(config);

pool.connect((err, client, done) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Error acquiring client', err.stack);
    return;
  }

  const testQuery = 'SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables';
  client.query(testQuery, (err, result) => {
    done();
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error executing query', err.stack);
      return;
    }
    console.log('Query result:', result.rows);
    pool.end();
  });
});
```

Before running the script I am exporting the `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=../aws-global-bundle.pem` where the `.pem` file is [this](https://truststore.pki.rds.amazonaws.com/global/global-bundle.pem) one.

My question is how can I enforce the `verify-full` option as described in the official `postgresql` [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-ssl.html#LIBQ-SSL-CERTIFICATES) and what is the practical difference with setting the `rejectUnauthorized` to `true` ?

I have tried the following

```js
config.ssl = { 
  rejectUnauthorized: true,
  sslmode: 'verify-full',
  ca: fs.readFileSync('./global-bundle.pem').toString(),
};
```

However it is as if the `sslmode: 'verify-full',` is not actually being taken into account because when I use `sslmode: 'foobar',` it does not complain at all (and connects as expected.

Comment: The link you give is to the libpq client library.  "Node" does not use this library, so that documentation doesn't apply to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'sslmode' and 'verify-full' are from libpq.  node pg is not based on libpq, so there is no reason for it to care about those settings.

My understanding is that `rejectUnauthorized: true` has about the same meaning as `sslmode=verify-full` does, they are just different libraries' ways of doing the same thing.

The only thing your example demonstrates is that config.ssl ignores noise keywords.  If you want to demonstrate whether the host name is actually being verified, you could do that by replacing the real *.pem file with some dummy one which is not the signing authority. Or you could replace the hostname in the connection string with the IP address of that host.